# Check identical numbers in Excel

Tags: windows-xp

I have two columns, some of which contain identical numbers.

I need to find out which of those are identical and which are not.

```
A          B          Results
370025946
370105427
390702269
430804504
450301915
450801217
470407476
480110158
491002440
491004010
500042551
500128111
500511233
510113303
           810112140
310927799
370025946
370105427
400021480
430028385
430103883
430804504
450107990
450301915
450801217
460002147
480110158
491002440
```

The `Results` column should contain "True" if any of the rows contains the same value:

1. In column A
2. In column B
3. In both columns

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1),COUNTIF(A:B,A1)>1,COUNTIF(A:B,B1)>1)
```

(To be used in ex. the C-column)

This will show "True" if the value is present in the A column more than once.